# Is there a formula for nested quadratic functions?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

Notation: $f^{(1)} (x) = f(x) \\ f^{(n)} (x) = f\left( f^{(n-1)}(x) \right)$

I'm looking for an explicit function, $f^{(n)} (x)$, where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary degree $2$ polynomial, or a nested quadratic.

I know there's a function for nested linear functions, $f(x) = mx+b \implies f^{(n)} (x) = m^n x + b\left( {m^n -1 \over m-1} \right)$, and $f(x) = x+b \implies f^{(n)} (x) = x+nb$.

I've been examining different kinds of quadratic functions, trying to find an explicit formula, but I can't catch the pattern. I know that $f(x) = ax^2 \implies f^{(n)}(x) = a^{2^n -1}x^{2^n}$, but I can't find a formula for $f(x) = x^2 +b$

I know it's a certain polynomial of the form $f(x) = x^2 +b \implies f^{(n)} (x) = x^{2^n} + \cdots + f^{(n)}(b)$, where the $\cdots$ are some chaotic behaving terms in the middle there, but it's the middle terms that I can't figure out.

Comment: Probably not much useful in the way of closed formula, I'm guessing.

Comment: Au contraire, I've found a formula for $\sinh^{-1} x$ which uses a nested quadratic, namely $f(x) = x^2 -2$. 
$\sinh^{-1} x = \lim_{n\to \infty} {1 \over 2^n} \ln \left( f^{(n)} (4x^2 +2) \right)$

Comment: Sorry, chose an obscure idiom "nothing useful in the way of," which does not mean that a closed form wouldn't be useful, just that I don't think there is a useful close formula.

Comment: Oh, well that's unfortunate, then.

Comment: Rob, $x^2 - 2$ is the only one that works. Indeed, repeating it gives $$ A^{(2^n)} + B^{(2^n)}  $$ for appropriate constants $A,B.$ Oh, $AB=1.$